# Where I need to place ruby-trello gem's config code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, trello

I am creating rails API app for managing Trello related boards and lists.
I have decided to use "ruby-trello" gem.

There is a config example at github ruby-trello page (https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello).

Config looks like this:

```
Trello.configure do |config|
  config.developer_public_key = 'my_trello_key'
  config.member_token = 'my_trello_token'
end
```

I got key and token from trello devs.
I have added this code to my config/application.rb in class Application.
But when I am trying to get something data from Trello I see this error:

```
Trello::ConfigurationError (Trello has not been configured to make authorized requests.)
```

Can anybody help? Where I need to place this config code?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails convention is to put that in `config/initializers/trello.rb` so that it's picked up when Rails boots.

It's odd they don't seem to mention that in the documentation.

Comment: What if i am not using Rails. Or does this gem only work in Rails context

Comment: @justintime In that case you can put that configuration code anywhere you please, just so long as it runs before you use the `Trello` module.